# Whatsapp message for a new number

Tags: ios, whatsapp, uiapplication

Hi as far as I know `whatsapp` support `abid` and `text` parameters like below:

```
NSURL *whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"whatsapp://send?text=Hello%2C%20World!"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
}
```

But I want to send message to a new number. For example if my number is **+123456**

```
NSURL *whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"whatsapp://send?abid=+123456"];
```

This doesn't work.

Because if the user insert the customer's `whatsapp` number, the App should popup the `whatsapp` message box with this number.

I noticed in some cases i can send message to number which is not listed in contact list. im wondering how it works.

Comment: An `abid` is not a phone number, but the ID of the contact in the addressbook.

Comment: @rckoenes is there any solution to my problem? because i am testing with real whatsapp able number.

Comment: Read the answer by Shaggy, your answer is there.

Answer (score 3):

From [WhatsApp docs](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013) :

abid :  **Address book ID** of contact to start a chat with. If contact with this ID has only one whatsapp-able phone number, application will open a conversation with that contact. If contact with this ID has more than one whatsapp-able phone numbers, application will present a menu with all phone numbers available for chat. **If contact has no whatsapp-able phone numbers, or contact with this ID does not exist, or this parameter is missing, application will present contact picker listing all contacts available for chat via WhatsApp.**

As we read above , `abid` is not the phone number, rather is it the Address Book ID of the destination contact.

As you say, you have to use a **new** number, a contact picker will open up first and allow to select a contact from it.

Comment: if the number is whatsapp able number is there anyway to send ?

Comment: NO, because the parameter is not meant for passing phone number, it is meant for passing ID of the contact, please check my edit.

Comment: have you ever noticed some time we can send message to number which is not listed in contact list. why cant we do that programatically ?

Comment: Are you talking about iPhone? Can we do that on iPhone dialpad?